# Jenkins Upgrade via WAR file but Win Installed list shows original version

Tags: jenkins

When upgrading Jenkins via replacement WAR file when we go into Jenkins all is showing correctly as the new updated version. However, The Windows Control Panel "Programs & Features" Still shows as the original version which was fully installed.
is there a way this can be updated (registry) as I'm concerned that an future scans of our system for old software will still flag this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has turned out to not be an issue as the health checking software does not look at this.